# Jquery image slider doesn't work on macintosh

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

My jquery image slider doesn't work on Macintosh at all. It works fine in Windows on all browsers. Can anyone tell me why? I'm very new to this. I believe everything for the slider is here. I can post the rest of my css if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you've specified images on a C: drive, which does not exist on the Mac?  Can't you just use relative paths, and put the `slider/images` directory in the same directory as the rest of your project?